# Custom Dialog Fragment resize on soft keyboard popup

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dialogfragment that is fullscreen on smaller screens but has certain dimensions for larger screens.

The dialog has an edit text field and a couple of action buttons in the footer.
I need the dialog fragment to resize such that the buttons are above the soft keyboard when the keyboard is in focus.

On smaller screens, the following snippet ensures the dialog resize.

```
<style name="fullScreenDialog" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

For larger screens, the dimensions are set as follows.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (EPHelper.deviceHasLargeScreen()) {
        Dialog d = getDialog();
        Window w = d.getWindow();

        if (dimenH > 0 && dimenW > 0) {
            w.setLayout(dimenW, dimenH);
        }
```

I tried using the SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE in the onViewCreated

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Window w = getDialog().getWindow();
    w.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I commented out the code to set the layout dimensions and viola it works. So it seems like setting the layout params hinders the resize.

- I could make the layout height smaller such that the keyboard fits
  but it seems hacky.
- Another option is to resize the dialog fragment when the soft keyboard is shown.

Is there a better/recommended way to get both of these to work together --> 
Custom screen size for the dialog fragment and screen resize when soft keyboard is shown.

Comment: hav u tried with adjustPan?

Comment: Yes and adjustPan wouldnt resize the window, so the footer would still be hidden.

Comment: use both `adjustResize|adjustPan` and try..

Comment: Not sure what you base that on.
 FYI, those 2 are exclusive and only one of them can be used.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: did you find a way?